# error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'yRatio')

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apex-chart

Tengo el siguiente error,

```
apexcharts:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'yRatio')
    at t.value (apexcharts:6:352617)
    at t.value (apexcharts:6:380452)
    at t.value (apexcharts:14:38768)
    at t.create (apexcharts:6:4705)
    at apexcharts:14:37129
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at t.value (apexcharts:14:21643)
    at graficar (EstadisticasPerdidas:463:10)
    at Object.success (EstadisticasPerdidas:419:6)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:28017)
value @ apexcharts:6
value @ apexcharts:6
value @ apexcharts:14
(anonymous) @ apexcharts:6
(anonymous) @ apexcharts:14
value @ apexcharts:14
graficar @ EstadisticasPerdidas:463
success @ EstadisticasPerdidas:419
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
A @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ EstadisticasPerdidas:402
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Estoy intentado de hacer una consulta y los datos que me trae me los grafique, Aquí coloco el javascript que me trae los datos

```
$("#form-graficar").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();
        ruta = $(this).attr("action");

        $.ajax({
            url: ruta,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                var dias = new Array();
                var salida = new Array();
                var ganancia = new Array();
                var producto = new Array();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    dias.push(value.mes);
                    valor = Number(value.ganancia);
                    ganancia.push(valor);
                    producto.push(value.producto);
                    salida.push(value.salida);
                });
                graficar(dias, salida, ganancia);
            }
        })
    })
```

y me lo convierte en json, está 100% funcionando porque lo imprimí como un html y me trajó los datos solicitados.
Este es el controlador que me trae los datos o que me define ruta:url

```
public function gananciaMes()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $idproducto = $this->input->post('producto');
        $fecha = $this->input->post('fecha');
        $fecha2 = $this->input->post('fecha2');
        $resultados = $this->model_backend->gananciaMes($id,$idproducto,$fecha,$fecha2);
        echo json_encode($resultados);
    }
```

y esta es la consulta que 100% me está funcionando

```
public function gananciaMes($id,$idproducto,$fecha,$fecha2)
{
    $this->db->select('Date(g.fecha) AS mes,  p.producto as producto, SUM(g.ganancias) AS ganacias, SUM(g.salida) AS salida');
    $this->db->from('ganancia g');
    $this->db->join('producto p', 'g.producto_id = p.id');
    $this->db->where('g.sede_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('g.producto_id', $idproducto);
    $this->db->where(array('g.fecha >='=>$fecha));
    $this->db->where(array('g.fecha <='=>$fecha2));
    $this->db->group_by("Date(g.fecha) , p.producto ");
    $this->db->order_by('Date(g.fecha)');

    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    if ($resultados->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $resultados->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

el error está aquí donde me intenta graficar los datos o traer

```
function graficar(dias, salida, ganancia) {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'monto',
                    data: ganancia
                }, {
                    name: 'monto',
                    data: salida
                }],

                stroke: {
                    show: true,
                    width: 3
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        columnWidth: '90%',
                        distributed: true,
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    labels: {
                        rotate: -45
                    },
                    categories: dias,
                    tickPlacement: 'on'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Dias',
                    },
                },
            }

            var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
            chart.render();

        }
```

si depronto necesita el formulario donde guardo y envio los datos

```
<form id="form-graficar" action="<?= base_url() ?>Ultra/gananciaMes" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="form-label">Producto:</label>
        <select name="producto" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" style="height: 28px;" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option selected>seleccione un producto </option>

                <?php foreach ($producto as $p) { ?>

                <option value="<?= $p->id ?>"> <?= $p->producto ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="form-label">Desde</label>
            <input type="date" name="fecha" id="">
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="form-label">Hasta</label>
            <input type="date" name="fecha2" id="">
        </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <label for="form-label">Sede: </label>
      <input type="text" name="id" id="" placeholder="     ID">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
```

estoy dispuesto a aceptar cualquier sugerencia o idea

Comment: es column o bar??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el error es que pusiste chart type `column` en vez de `bar` en las opciones :

```js
var dias = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var salida = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
var ganancia = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000];

graficar(dias, salida, ganancia);

function graficar(dias, salida, ganancia) {
  var options = {
    chart: {
      // intenta cambiar type: "column" por type: "bar"
      type: 'bar',
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'monto',
        data: ganancia,
      },
      {
        name: 'monto',
        data: salida,
      },
    ],

    stroke: {
      show: true,
      width: 3,
    },

    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        columnWidth: '90%',
        distributed: true,
      },
    },
    xaxis: {
      labels: {
        rotate: -45,
      },
      categories: dias,
      tickPlacement: 'on',
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Dias',
      },
    },
  };

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
  chart.render();
}
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: si y el error indica que esta intentando acceder a la propiedad yRatio que no existe en el arreglo que le esta pasando al chart.